# discordpy: Why is the bot keep going offline in FastAPI?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using discord bot in FastAPI just to check members in current some voice channels.

and I'm running this in AWS EC2 with `nohup python server.py &`

But after some time the bot just goes offline (not fastapi), I wanted to check if the bot is offline to reconnect and also messages in real time but on_message never called

Thanks in advance.

```py
import asyncio

import discord
import uvicorn
from discord.ext import commands
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

# Discord
TOKEN = ""
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=intents)
names = ["~", "~", "~"]
channels = ["~", "~", "~"]

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startUp():
    asyncio.create_task(bot.start(TOKEN))

def getDiscordUsers():
    json = {name: [] for name in names}

    for i in range(0, 3):
        channel = bot.get_channel(channels[i])
        members = channel.members
        for member in members:
            selfMuted = member.voice.self_mute
            if member.bot:
                continue
            if member.nick == None:
                json[names[i]].append(f"{member.name}")
            else:
                json[names[i]].append(member.nick)

    return json

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)  # it seems never called becuz of fastapi coroutine?


@app.get("/discord")
async def get_users():
    # if not bot.is_ready():
    #     print("called")
    #     asyncio.create_task(bot.connect())
    return getDiscordUsers()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="info")
```

Comment: i know discord.py but not a lot about fast API ext but I am pretty sure if you self host the bot it does the same you have to ping the bot or have some kind of a request to the bot or from the bot in order for it to not go offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems better to call serve() in bot's loop when using discord.py with FastAPI

and I can even use bot.command, event stuff

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from fastapi import FastAPI
from uvicorn import Config, Server

TOKEN = "TOKEN"
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("["):
        print("yes")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready)")


async def getDiscordUsers():
    json = {name: [] for name in names}

    for i in range(0, 3):
        channel = bot.get_channel(channels[i])
        members = channel.members
        for member in members:
            # selfMuted = member.voice.self_mute
            if member.bot:
                continue
            if member.nick == None:
                json[names[i]].append(member.name)
            else:
                json[names[i]].append(member.nick)

    return json


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/discord")
async def send_msg():
    return await getDiscordUsers()


config = Config(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="critical")
server = Server(config)

bot.loop.create_task(server.serve())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```